# How do I get the coordinates of the client window file menu bar?

Tags: c#, winapi

When I use ClientToScreen() I get the coordinates of the client window, but it does not include the file menu bar. This is only a problem for me when a window has a file menu bar, e.g. the windows calculator.

[image: calculator image]

```
public Point createPoint(IntPtr handle)
{
    Point myPoint = new Point(0, 0);
    Point myPointClient = new Point(0, 0);
    RECT myRectWindow;
    if (radioButtonEntireWindow.Checked)   // Green cross
    {
        // Result: (0, 0)
    }
    else if (radioButtonClientWindowFileMenu.Checked)   // Red cross
    {
        // This works for windows 7, but probably not for windows 10:
        myPoint = new Point(8, 30);
        // Result: (8, 30)
    }
    else if (radioButtonClientWindow.Checked)   // Purple cross
    {
        GetWindowRect(handle, out myRectWindow);
        ClientToScreen(handle, ref myPointClient);
        myPoint = new Point(myPointClient.X - myRectWindow.Location.X, myPointClient.Y - myRectWindow.Location.Y);
        // Result: (8, 50)
    }
    return myPoint;
}
```

How do I get the red cross coordinates without explicitly using (8, 30)? Using GetWindowRect() and GetClientRect() to get the title bar height does not work because it does not include the file menu bar, just like ClientToScreen().

Comment: Apps that use the native window menu start their client area below the menu bar.  The menu itself is in the non-client area.  Some do, some don't, compare Winforms MainMenu control vs MenuStrip for example.  GetMenu() will return a non-null menu handle, GetMenuBarInfo() returns its size.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not using winforms. I am looking to do this with e.g. Chrome or the windows calculator

Comment: Just an example, that is why I recommended the winapi functions.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Sounds like a question, where the answer is UI Automation.

Comment: @IInspectable I am trying to take a screenshot of either the client window area or the client window area with the file menu bar of e.g. the windows calculator

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties of System.Windows.SystemParameters to get the sizes of various elements, for instance it has a MenuBarHeight andCaptionBarHeight property.

Comment: Can I somehow get the caption bar height of chrome?

Comment: @Xrio: No. Chrome uses custom rendering for its entire UI.

Comment: The sizes of elements can vary for each window because of DPI and multi-monitor setups, Windows 10 now has GetSystemMetricsForDPI etc.

Answer (score 0):

The native menu bar is outside the HWNDs client area. Some windows also use a custom menu bar and all bets are off in those cases, it could be inside or outside the client area.

You can detect if a window has a native menu bar by calling [`GetMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640(v=vs.85).aspx).

You cannot really use the system metrics (`SM_CYMENU` etc.) to find the size of it because:

- Windows can have different DPI support, some might be scaled/stretched and some are native size. Can also depend on which monitor they are on.
- The menu bar can have multiple lines if the window is too narrow to display all the items on one line.

If you just want to know if some point on the screen is a menu bar you can send the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618(v=vs.85).aspx) message and compare the return value with `HTMENU`.

To get the size of a native menu bar you can do something like this (posting in plain C, sorry):

```
HWND hCalc = FindWindow(TEXT("CalcFrame"), NULL);
HMENU hMenu = hCalc ? GetMenu(hCalc) : NULL;
MENUBARINFO mbi;
printf("Menu of %p is %p\n", hCalc, hMenu);
mbi.cbSize = sizeof(MENUBARINFO);
if (GetMenuBarInfo(hCalc, OBJID_MENU, 0, &mbi))
{
    printf("GetMenuBarInfo: pos:%dx%d size:%dx%d\n", mbi.rcBar.left, mbi.rcBar.top, mbi.rcBar.right - mbi.rcBar.left, mbi.rcBar.bottom - mbi.rcBar.top);
}
```

I would however recommend that you use MSAA or UI Automation because it can also work in applications with custom menu bars:

```
OleInitialize(0);
HWND hCalc = FindWindow(TEXT("CalcFrame"), NULL);
IAccessible*pAcc;
HRESULT hr;
hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hCalc, OBJID_MENU, IID_IAccessible, (void**) &pAcc);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{

    long x, y, w, h;
    VARIANT v;
    V_VT(&v) = VT_I4;
    V_I4(&v) = CHILDID_SELF;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pAcc->accLocation(&x, &y, &w, &h, v)))
    {
        printf("pos: %dx%d size: %dx%d\n", x, y, w, h);
    }
    pAcc->Release();
}
```

and the same thing with PInvoke calls:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Accessibility;

namespace Test
{
class TestApp 
{


[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, IntPtr zero);

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1060:MovePInvokesToNativeMethodsClass"), DllImport("oleacc.dll", ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = false)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
static extern object AccessibleObjectFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, uint dwObjectID, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid);

static Guid IID_IAccessible = new Guid("{618736E0-3C3D-11CF-810C-00AA00389B71}");

enum OBJID : uint { WINDOW = 0x00000000, SYSMENU = 0xFFFFFFFF, TITLEBAR = 0xFFFFFFFE, MENU = 0xFFFFFFFD, CLIENT = 0xFFFFFFFC, }


static void Main() 
{
    IntPtr hCalc = FindWindow("CalcFrame", IntPtr.Zero);
    Console.WriteLine("Calc HWND is "+hCalc);
    if (hCalc == IntPtr.Zero) return ;
    try
    {
        IAccessible acc = (IAccessible) AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hCalc, (uint)OBJID.CLIENT, IID_IAccessible);
        int x, y, w, h;
        acc.accLocation(out x, out y, out w, out h, null);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("pos: {0}x{1} size:{2}x{3}", x, y, w, h));
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
    {
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: I am unable to determine what the idObject / OBJID_MENU is supposed to be? Is this supposed to be the hMenu?

Comment: No, it is a constant. Its value is 0xFFFFFFFD.

Comment: Any drawbacks to using UI Automation?

Comment: You can use System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromHandle if you want to use UI Automation in .NET instead. You then probably have to walk the child tree trying find the menu.

Comment: I would accept this as the answer if the code was in c#